# Python - Selenium error on Ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, selenium, vps

I've a strange problem with Python (or maybe I'm only a noob).

I wrote a little bot to automate some action on the browser using selenium and I want to run on a Ubuntu VPS, so I've installed Selenium and the other modules I needed and I ran the script but when it comes to the first of this lines

```
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "free_play_captcha_types")))
driver.find_element_by_id("free_play_captcha_types").click()
driver.find_element_by_id("free_play_captcha_types").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//option[contains(@value, 'recaptcha_v1')]").click()
```

I get the `socket.error: errno [111] Connection refused` error.

I've already tried to run the selenium server before running the script but nothing changes... has someone have an advice?

Thank you in advance.

Another information: I ran the same script on a different VPS and it ran successfully...

Comment: it sounds like your VPS is blocking the connection out. are you able to load the website in the VPS outside of Selenium?

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/a/50570227/4513879

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Selenium - socket.error: \[Errno 111\] Connection refused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50569160/selenium-socket-error-errno-111-connection-refused)