# Selenium - socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Tags: python, django, selenium

I'm trying to create Selenium tests for my web application. So far I have:

```
from selenium import webdriver
import httplib

driver = webdriver.Chrome('v1/chromedriver-Linux64')
#in tutorial, it was just webdriver.Chrome() but that didn't work

url = "http://127.0.0.1:8000/loty/accounts/login/"
try: 
    driver.get(url)
except httplib.BadStatusLine as bsl:
    pass
#in tutorial, it was just driver.get(url) but that didn't work

driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#menu")
```

Unfortunately, I get a [long traceback](https://pastebin.com/ra07ymAu) ending with `socket.error: [Errno 111] Connection refused`. How can I get it to work?

Comment: When you run this code, do you know if your selenium server running?

Comment: I don't think I have any selenium server. I just run the script from Pycharm (right click -> run 'test') or alternatively run it from virtualenv (source bin/activate, python test.py). Both ways give the same error.

Comment: Have you downloaded any geckodriver for chrome?

Comment: I've downloaded chromedriver, trying 'pip install geckodriver' gives 'Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement geckodriver (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for geckodriver
'

Comment: Ah ok, what version of chrome you have and what geckodriver version have you installed?

Comment: Chromedriver is 2.24.1, I think. As I said, I don't have geckodriver installed. Chrome is 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've chrome driver which doesn't support your version of chrome browser.
v65-67 is supported by chromedriver 2.38. so it seems a config issue. Use below to install latest version of chrome driver.

http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads

Comment: that seems to have solved it, at least for now. Thanks a lot!